# Open stock information database?

Tags: equities, market-data, historical-data

I know I can get stock prices from Yahoo Finance or Quandl, but does anyone know where to get stock information? i.e., industry, country, sedol, primary exchange

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Bloomberg, Reuters?

Comment: As in a data service like quandl, rather than having to scrape

Answer (score 1):

This kind of data you are looking for is - as far as I know - not available for free.

**Stock segmentation** depends on various aspects and there are professional agencies that do this job. While MSCI, for example, classifies a stock in Sector A, STOXX classifies it into Sector B.

Also **primary exchange** depends on various aspects and Bloomberg and Thomson Reuters use different methods to evaluate the primay exchange.

**SEDOL numbers**: see here: http://www.londonstockexchange.com/products-and-services/reference-data/sedol-master-file/sedol-master-file.htm

Comment: Pretty much the same for country, the stock can be incorporated in country A, listed in country B and have its headquarters in country C.  Bloomberg and Reuters provide all of the above information.